# Why does math with ULong > 16 digits get wonky?

Tags: .net, vb.net, math, .net-core, radix

I am working on a "simple" base converter to convert ULong with base 10 to a String with any base. Here I use 64 chars. Usecase is to shorten ULong that are stored as String anyway.

```
Public Class BaseConverter
    'base64, but any length would work
    Private Shared ReadOnly Characters() As Char = {"0"c, "1"c, "2"c, "3"c, "4"c, "5"c, "6"c, "7"c, "8"c, "9"c,
                                                    "a"c, "b"c, "c"c, "d"c, "e"c, "f"c, "g"c, "h"c, "i"c, "j"c, "k"c, "l"c, "m"c, "n"c, "o"c, "p"c, "q"c, "r"c, "s"c, "t"c, "u"c, "v"c, "w"c, "x"c, "y"c, "z"c,
                                                    "A"c, "B"c, "C"c, "D"c, "E"c, "F"c, "G"c, "H"c, "I"c, "J"c, "K"c, "L"c, "M"c, "N"c, "O"c, "P"c, "Q"c, "R"c, "S"c, "T"c, "U"c, "V"c, "W"c, "X"c, "Y"c, "Z"c,
                                                    "+"c, "-"c}

    Public Shared Function Encode(number As ULong) As String
        Dim buffer = New Text.StringBuilder()
        Dim quotient = number
        Dim remainder As ULong
        Dim base = Convert.ToUInt64(Characters.LongLength)

        Do
            remainder = quotient Mod base
            quotient = quotient \ base
            buffer.Insert(0, Characters(remainder).ToString())
        Loop While quotient <> 0

        Return buffer.ToString()
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Decode(str As String) As ULong
        If String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str) Then Return 0

        Dim result As ULong = 0
        Dim base = Convert.ToUInt64(Characters.LongLength)
        Dim nPos As ULong = 0

        For i As Integer = str.Length - 1 To 0 Step - 1
            Dim cPos As Integer = Array.IndexOf(Of Char)(Characters, str(i))
            result += (base ^ nPos) * Convert.ToUInt64(cPos)
            nPos += 1
        Next
        Return result
    End Function
End Class
```

It works fine with numbers up to 16 digits, but when the number has more digits it starts to *round* weird.

17 digits result in jumps of 8, 18 digits result in jumps of 32 and 19 digits result in jumps of 256.

For example, these numbers around **42347959784570944** do not work and result in those *blocks*:

```
42347959784570939 > 2msPWXX00X > 42347959784570936 ERROR
42347959784570940 > 2msPWXX00Y > 42347959784570944 ERROR
42347959784570941 > 2msPWXX00Z > 42347959784570944 ERROR
42347959784570942 > 2msPWXX00+ > 42347959784570944 ERROR
42347959784570943 > 2msPWXX00- > 42347959784570944 ERROR
42347959784570944 > 2msPWXX010 > 42347959784570944
42347959784570945 > 2msPWXX011 > 42347959784570944 ERROR
42347959784570946 > 2msPWXX012 > 42347959784570944 ERROR
42347959784570947 > 2msPWXX013 > 42347959784570944 ERROR
42347959784570948 > 2msPWXX014 > 42347959784570944 ERROR
42347959784570949 > 2msPWXX015 > 42347959784570952 ERROR
```

The problem has to be in the **Decode()** function, as the generated strings differ.

I put some tests on https://dotnetfiddle.net/7wAGLh, but I just can't find the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The exponent operator, `^`, [always returns a `Double`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/exponentiation-operator#result).
This [means](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/data-types-of-operator-results) the entire expression `(base ^ nPos) * Convert.ToUInt64(cPos)` is evaluated and returned as `Double` (and then silently crammed into a `ULong`).

Which brings in the [`Double` imprecision](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32783923/11683) that you are observing.

Using [`Option Strict On`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) at all times is a good way to catch these errors.

Provided that you know that `(base ^ nPos)` will not exceed the maximum value of `ULong` (which seems to be the assumption anyway), the fix is

```vb
result += CULng(base ^ nPos) * Convert.ToUInt64(cPos)
```